# How can i manage both button of navigation bar when scrolling table with large navigation title?

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, preferslargetitles

[image]here i can attached screenshots which i faced as an issue when scrolling at time i want to hide that more button or put that button into navigation bar as 2nd button but it's override to 1st one.

i set button into did load by calling simply this function.

```
func setUpNavigationMoreButton() {
    let rightButton = UIButton()
    let btnFilterImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DotsThreeOutline")
    rightButton.setImage(btnFilterImage, for: .normal)
    rightButton.setTitleColor(.purple, for: .normal)
    rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(filterClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(rightButton)
    rightButton.tag = 1
    rightButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    
    let targetView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    
    let trailingContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightButton, attribute:
            .trailingMargin, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: targetView,
                                               attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -16)
    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: rightButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: targetView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -6)
    rightButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([trailingContraint, bottomConstraint])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to hide/unhide the more button when the Large title changes.

```
class VController: UIViewController {

    let rightButton = UIButton()
    var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.observer = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.observe(\.bounds, options: [.new], changeHandler: { (navigationBar, changes) in
            if let height = changes.newValue?.height {
                if height > 44.0 {
                    //Large Title, unhide button
                    rightButton.isHidden = false
                } else {
                    //Small Title, hide button
                    rightButton.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Thank you... it's great work for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem) instead of a UIButton.

```
let btnFilterImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DotsThreeOutline")
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: btnFilterImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(filterClick))
    
navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

If you have multiple buttons

```
let rightButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: image1, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(filterClick))

let rightButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(image: image2, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(filterClick))

navigationController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [rightButton1, rightButton2]
```

Comment: thank you for response but if i used this type of bar button than it's show me into top as like search button i need more button align to title and when i scroll at that time i need more button near to search.

Comment: can you share some screens

Comment: yes, i updated screenshots

Comment: @NiravParmar231 added a new answer. You can observe the navigation bar height changes and hide or unhide your button accordingly.